# $y=\arcsin xy;\quad xy'+y=y'\sqrt{1-x^2 y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem says that the left function is an implicit solution of that differential equation and I have to prove it. My try: $$x\frac{y+xy'}{\sqrt{1-(xy)^2}}+\arcsin xy=\text{ ?}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Please avoid asking more than one question in each post.

Comment: I changed x² to x^2 and y² to y^2, so it looks like $x^2$ and $y^2$ rather than $x²$ and $y²$.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation $y = \arcsin(xy)$ implies that $xy = \sin(y)$. Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, you obtain
$$xy' + y = y'\cos(y).$$
But $\cos(y) = \cos(\arcsin(xy))$...

Comment: Is $\cos(\arcsin(xy))$ something I should know what it gives? I found in wikipedia that $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ but then the solution would be $xy'+y=y'\sqrt{1-(xy)^2}$

Comment: Exactly. I'm guessing there's a typo in the title (in the actual question you write $\sqrt{1-(xy)^2}$).